# SQL Select Join with a limit in Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My original query searched the motherboards, then found images for the motherboards. But now, some of the motherboards do not have any image associated so I want to run one query that can find 20 unique motherboards with images.

Code so far:

```
$newMotherboards = Motherboards::join('images', 'motherboards.motherboard_id', '=', 'images.item_id')
    ->where('images.item_type', '=', 'motherboard')
    ->orderBy('motherboards.date_added', 'desc')
    ->take(20)
    ->get();
```

I have even tried selecting specific results:

```
$newMotherboards = Motherboards::join('images', 'motherboards.motherboard_id', '=', 'images.item_id')
    ->select('motherboards.motherboard_id', 'motherboards.name')
    ->where('images.item_type', '=', 'motherboard')
    ->orderBy('motherboards.date_added', 'desc')
    ->take(20)
    ->get();
```

The problem with the code above is that when I loop through each $newMotherboards, it has duplicates for every image that exists with its ID. I only want to retrieve 20 unique motherboards where they were added the most recently, but have images.

If an item has 5 images and it is one of the recent 20 added, then it will appear five times of my 20 limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinct version:

```
    $newMotherboards = Motherboards::join('images', 'motherboards.motherboard_id', '=', 'images.item_id')
        ->select('motherboards.motherboard_id', 'motherboards.name')
        ->where('images.item_type', '=', 'motherboard')
        ->distinct()
        ->orderBy('motherboards.date_added', 'desc')
        ->take(20)
        ->get();
```

Groupby version:

```
    $newMotherboards = Motherboards::join('images', 'motherboards.motherboard_id', '=', 'images.item_id')
        ->select('motherboards.motherboard_id', 'motherboards.name')
        ->where('images.item_type', '=', 'motherboard')
        ->groupby('images.item_type')
        ->orderBy('motherboards.date_added', 'desc')
        ->take(20)
        ->get();
```