# Laravel join with limit

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following working for laravel paginate

```
$query = DB::table('clients')
            ->leftJoin('radusergroup', 'clients.username', '=', 'radusergroup.username')
            ->leftJoin('recharge', 'clients.username', '=', 'recharge.soldto');
```

I want to join some values from two tables radusergroup and recharge. radusergroup always return one row as it has only one row stored whereas recharge table return multiple rows. I want only one row returned from recharge table which is latest entry.

Right now its return all the possible rows from recharge table and showing it on paginated view.

Comment: Try this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849719/sql-select-join-with-a-limit-in-laravel-php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Laravel Official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins)

```
DB::table('clinets')
     ->leftJoin('radusergroup', 'clients.username', '=', 'radusergroup.username')
    ->leftJoin('recharge', function ($leftJoin) {
        $leftJoin->on('clients.username', '=', 'recharge.soldto')
             ->where('recharge.create_date', '=', DB::raw("(select max(`create_date`) from recharge)"));
    })
    ->get();
```

this is the case if you have create_date column in your table, if you haven't got it I strongly recommend to create that column.

Comment: I already have date column called 'salesdate' in recharge table. However running your query returns the following error. Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select max(`salesdate`) from recharge) ?' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `clients` left join `radusergroup` on `clients`.`username` = `radusergroup`.`username` left join `recharge` on `clients`.`username` = `recharge`.`soldto` and `recharge`.`salesdate` (select max(`salesdate`) from recharge) )

Comment: Working now. It was missing '=' in                                                                   ->where('recahrge.create_date', DB::raw("(select max(`create_date`) from recahrge)"));